# Uncheck radio button Angular ui-bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

My function:

```
$scope.DownloadedUncheck = function (event) {
     if (event.target.value === lastChecked) {
        delete $scope.$parent.selectedDownloaded
        lastChecked = null
     } else {
        lastChecked = event.target.value
        delete $scope.$parent.selectedDownloading
     }
};
```

Here's my plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/g1t4pludTTIAJYKTToCK?p=preview

I wan't to uncheck radio button after click on it.
My code works with normal radio, but not with ui.bootstrap.
Thanks for asnwers in advance!

Comment: Your code in the plunker doesn't show any check box. Kindly fix it then probably I will get a better idea as to where the issue is.

Comment: The plunker is changed but there is still no radio button in it.

Comment: Why do you need a radio button for this? if you only have to toggle between 2 states, why not use a check box.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/GWKVrMxYEL9QhdwJIVUA?p=preview

Comment: @GopalkrishnaNarayanPrabhu Here is btn-radio from bootstrap

Comment: @SachetGupta I need radio button

Comment: and you want to de-select the previously checked radio button, once you click on it again ?

Comment: @SachetGupta Yes

Comment: @bafix2203 in the plunker  
plnkr.co/edit/GWKVrMxYEL9QhdwJIVUA?p=preview what is the exact functionality expected? when i click on downloaded or to download button what is the expected outcome? and secondly i can see no radio button... Kindly elaborate..

Comment: @GopalkrishnaNarayanPrabhu I mean it -  When "downloaded" button is clicked table is filtered. When you click second time "downloaded", it should be uncheck and table not be filtered.

Comment: @bafix2203 im not able to understand the requirement

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you need:

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="FirstCtrl">

    <label class="btn btn-default" uib-btn-radio="'True'" ng-model="$parent.selectedDownloaded" uncheckable>Downloaded
      </label>
    <br />
    <label class="btn btn-default" uib-btn-radio="'False'" ng-model="$parent.selectedDownloaded" uncheckable>To Download
      </label>

    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="name in name | filter:{Download:selectedDownloaded}">
                <td>{{name.Download}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

Changes:

1. You don't have to bind a method on click.
2. Upgrade your bootstrap-tpls lib to ver 2.5.0
3. Use proper element name for bootstrap radio button. which is `uib-btn-radio`
4. Use `uncheckable` attribute of `uib-btn-radio`, to make that radio button un-check-able

[updated plnkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/HWbw7PcM8JciK6297auA?p=preview)